# WindowsBuilder, is it possible to generate tidy code?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, refactoring, code-generation

im using WindowsBuilder with Eclipse INDIGO .. the code generated by the WYSIWYG is not suitable for me , all the swing componentes are generated on the constructor! i want code to be extracted like this:

```
    private MiJPanel getPanel(){
    if(panel == null) {
        panel = new MiJPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setImagen("/recursos/fondo2.jpg");
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(getLblUsuario());
        panel.add(getLblClave());
        panel.add(getCmbJugadores());
        panel.add(getPwdClave());
        panel.add(getBtnEntrar());
    }
    return panel;
}
```

Every component with a "singleton" function that creates the componente and returns it, that make's the code way better and clear to work with on complex project's.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Sorry for that, i used this account some years ago with no interest in rating.. i will rate acept now the answers. Thanks

Comment: I found the answer to my own question :-)

Window / Preferences / WindowBuilder / Swing / Code Generation -> Default Code Generation set to Lazy :D

Great!

Comment: @mandril, it would be better if you put your comment as an answer. It is even [OK to ask and answer your own questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).